# Java Cassandra Datastax driver custom codec not handling collection types

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have defined a custom codec taking tutorial as a reference- https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver/java-driver/reference/customCodecs.html. Here is my codec impelementation: -

```
    package org.questqa.server.database.codecs;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;

import org.questqa.server.database.fetchers.UserInfoFetcher;
import org.questqa.server.entity.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.datastax.driver.core.DataType;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion;
import com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec;
import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException;

public class UserCodec extends TypeCodec<User>
{

    @Autowired
    UserInfoFetcher userFetcher;

    public UserCodec(DataType cqlType, Class<User> javaClass) 
    {
        super(cqlType, javaClass);
    }

    @Override
    public User deserialize(ByteBuffer buffer, ProtocolVersion arg1) `throws InvalidTypeException {`
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Executing deserialize");
        User user = new User();
        try {
            System.out.println("Size of ByteBuffer: " + `buffer.array().length);`
            String userId = new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("User id to set: " + userId);
            System.out.println("Setting user id...");
            user.setUserId(userId);
            System.out.println("User id set: " + user.getUserId());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }
    @Override
    public String format(User user) throws InvalidTypeException 
    {
        System.out.println("Executing format");
        return user.getUserId();
    }
    @Override
    public User parse(String userId) throws InvalidTypeException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Executing parse");
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(userId);
        return user;
    }
    @Override
    public ByteBuffer serialize(User user, ProtocolVersion arg1) throws `InvalidTypeException {`
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Executing serialize");
        ByteBuffer buffer = null;
        System.out.println("Userid to serialize: " + user.getUserId());
        try {
            buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(user.getUserId().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String bufferStr = new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("ByteBuffer to be returned: \nLength: " + `buffer.array().length +` 
                    "\nValue: " + bufferStr);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Basically, in serialize method, I'm trying to extract a userId string (using user.getUserId()), and then store it in my cassandra table as a userid string. In deserialize, I simply convert the given ByteBuffer instance to a string and return it.
This works perfectly fine for string, set and list when serializing (i.e., if I have a Set, the codec executes serialize() on each individual element of the set and stores the corresponding string in my casandra table). However, during deserializing a set field in cassandra, the deserialize method sends the entire set in the ByteBuffer object. I can see that the individual elements are there by analyzing the ByteBuffer object. Note that deserialize is executed on every element of the set. So, if the set has 5 elements, deserialize is executed 5 times, but each time, instead of sending the particular element in the ByteBuffer, it sends the entire set. 
So, I don't understand why this is doing and google hasn't been of much help. Any suggestions/solutions are most welcome as I've been stuck on this for quite a while now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AbstractCollectionCodec`](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/TypeCodec.java#L1723-L1870) is what `SetCodec` and `ListCodec` use to serialize/deserialize collections.  On deserialize, they pass the whole `ByteBuffer` that is positioned where the element begins (`ByteBuffer.position()`) and limited by the end of the individual element (`ByteBuffer.limit()`) to the underlying element codec (in this case, `UserCodec`).

When you call `buffer.array()` you are getting the entire backing array of the `ByteBuffer`, regardless of the position or limit.

What should work better for you is to use [`Bytes.getArray(ByteBuffer)`](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/Bytes.java#L166-L192) which returns you a byte array for the data between `limit` and `position`, i.e.:

```java
@Override
public User deserialize(ByteBuffer buffer, ProtocolVersion arg1) `throws InvalidTypeException {`
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Executing deserialize");
    User user = new User();
    try {
        byte[] data = Bytes.toArray(buffer);
        System.out.println("Size of ByteBuffer: " + data.length);
        String userId = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("User id to set: " + userId);
        System.out.println("Setting user id...");
        user.setUserId(userId);
        System.out.println("User id set: " + user.getUserId());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Since you are simply storing your `User` instance in C* as a string representing its `getUserId()`, what you could do instead is create an instance of [`MappingCodec`](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0.0/driver-extras/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/extras/codecs/MappingCodec.java) from the extras module that simply maps the `User <-> String (UserId)`, i.e.:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec;
import com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.MappingCodec;

public class UserCodec extends MappingCodec<User, String> {

    public UserCodec() {
        super(TypeCodec.varchar(), User.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected User deserialize(String userId) {
        return new User(userId);
    }

    @Override
    protected String serialize(User user) {
        return user.getUserId();
    }
}
```

You can read more about `MappingCodec` [on the docs site](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#abstract-utilities).

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really helpful!